# Numbers for macOS: how to update a column of entries

Tags: numbers

[image]In Numbers for macOS I have a column of entries, each entry (field) is just a single word. How can I update the whole column such that each entry will look like that instead:

```
<img src="field_content.jpg">
```

Comment: This is not clear to me.  Why can't copy/paste work?

Comment: @fsb I've added an image to help illustrate the problem. Copying and pasting won't work because I have many entries in that column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding an extra column and using a formula in this column. Press = key on the keyboard to open the formula window and enter the formula:
[image]
Then press the green button and copy paste the formula in other cells:
[image]

You can copy and paste the data into the original column afterwards (but use "Edit" - "Paste Formula Results" command this time).